# Update C# Windows Forms Project to Latest C# Version

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Forms project but I need to update it to the latest version of the C# language but I don't understand the documentation for updating, does anyone have an example of how to do this?

I'm using version 4.6 of Net Framework, I've tried it with 4.8 too

Comment: You need to provide specifics such as which .NET Framework is the current project along with what this project does, more details are better. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Net should work.  If you are using other version of c# like core always compile with Net library and then target the version of c# you are using.

Comment: Updating language (c#) is different from upgrading framework version. Do you know which c# version it was built in? Latest c# has lot of new features which makes it possible to do some things that would require more code or implementation details in older versions. For example dynamic types is a feature introduced in recent version, although it is not used much by developers yet. You will have to evaluate the need of such new features on case to case basis. Upgrading the framework is a completely different story, but your requirement seems to be on language upgrade so I am not commenting on it

Comment: You'll have to target .NETCore (aka .NET 6.0) if you want the latest C# version.  Try the [migration assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Btw, updating a project in .net is mostly a very straightforward process. Get the code, open it with latest visual studio, change the build target to choose .net framework you would like to go to. Once you build the code it may throw warnings/errors about deprecated code in old version. You will have to fix those individual errors/warnings to get to your new version. Although straightforward, this may be repetitive and time consuming process. Depends on complexity and volume of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the LangVersion property in the .csproj file to specify the C# version you'd like to use.  You can set it to a specific version, or use "latest" to set it to the latest version compatible with the compiler:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Be aware that only certain versions of the C# language are compatible with specific .NET versions *and* MSBuild Versions.  The highest version of C# compatible with .NET Framework is 7.3.

You can find more information, including C# / .NET version compatibility, here:

[C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)